# How can I get ETH balance with pending transaction?

Tags: balances

I use web3.eth.getBalance to get balance of a specific address. I want to get how amount of unconfirmed ETH the address has.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxx:xxxx"));

var balance = web3.eth.getBalance("0xbddf0bf3ac858d7fb8a2bdda55884d61779ba5a9");
console.log(balance.toNumber()); // Only confirmed balance is showed. I want to know unconfirmed balance
```

---

Update 1

Thanks to @niksmac. I tried to use web3.eth.filter. It seems that pending txes are showed. But it is a little bit strange. I set 0x11fd3ffc4243cac293ee3d349ec906a2786087fe as a specific address, however the address was not showed in the result. And I may have to get the amount of ETH by the transactionHash.

filter.js

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxx:xxx"));

var options = web3.eth.filter({address: "0x11fd3ffc4243cac293ee3d349ec906a2786087fe"});
var filter = web3.eth.filter(options);
var myResults = filter.get(function(error, logs){ console.log(logs); });
```

result

```
[ { address: '0x2a98c5f40bfa3dee83431103c535f6fae9a8ad38',
    topics: 
     [ '0x5a690ecd0cb15c1c1fd6b6f8a32df0d4f56cb41a54fea7e94020f013595de796',
       '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
       '0x0000000000000000000000002e8520ef2806ea0c0c3f02b24dddf0d23e58b5f8',
       '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' ],
    data: '0x58425455534400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockNumber: 1620014,
    transactionHash: '0xfc93b988bc65686b7f01f5f522ce13cd80c800674de386a82512d77246721b07',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x1e932b4902300dd352e5a0f1a446c92ac1d6373c1551acfc83d4b458171009ee',
    logIndex: 0,
    removed: false },
  { address: '0x2a98c5f40bfa3dee83431103c535f6fae9a8ad38',
    topics: 
     [ '0xa9c6cbc4bd352a6940479f6d802a1001550581858b310d7f68f7bea51218cda6',
       '0x5842545553440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' ],
    data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f53bab9c227ae40000',
    blockNumber: 1620014,
    transactionHash: '0xfc93b988bc65686b7f01f5f522ce13cd80c800674de386a82512d77246721b07',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x1e932b4902300dd352e5a0f1a446c92ac1d6373c1551acfc83d4b458171009ee',
    logIndex: 1,
    removed: false },
  { address: '0x2e8520ef2806ea0c0c3f02b24dddf0d23e58b5f8',
    topics: 
     [ '0xa609f6bd4ad0b4f419ddad4ac9f0d02c2b9295c5e6891469055cf73c2b568fff',
       '0x0000000000000000000000002e8520ef2806ea0c0c3f02b24dddf0d23e58b5f8' ],
    data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f3f22f14ecd9910000',
    blockNumber: 1620014,
    transactionHash: '0xfc93b988bc65686b7f01f5f522ce13cd80c800674de386a82512d77246721b07',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x1e932b4902300dd352e5a0f1a446c92ac1d6373c1551acfc83d4b458171009ee',
    logIndex: 2,
    removed: false } 
]
```

Comment: Post your finding/solution as an answer rather than updating the question.

Comment: You are right but I'm still looking into how to get the amount of balance from the result of filter. I will post it as an answer it if I can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont see any direct way to get this. But you can try [`web3.eth.filter`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter) with specifying the account address.

**Parameters**

1. `String|Object` - The string "latest" or "pending" to watch for changes in the latest block or pending transactions respectively. Or a filter options object as follows:
2. `fromBlock:` Number|String - The number of the earliest block (latest may be given to mean the most recent and pending currently mining, block).
3. `toBlock:` Number|String - The number of the latest block (latest may be given to mean the most recent and pending currently mining, block).
4. `address:` String - An address or a list of addresses to only get logs from particular account(s).
5. `topics:` Array of Strings - An array of values which must each appear in the log entries. The order is important, if you want to leave topics use null, e.g. [null, '0x00...'].

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying it right now. I posted the result of filter.

Comment: This would only return events. It would not work if the account has an incoming ETH transfer with no accompanying events. I posted a simple and effective answer below — I guess this wasn't available at the time the question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is ideal or not but the following way might be possible. This way can be used not only ETH transaction but also token txes if I can parse the input data.

(1) run watch daemon and save the txes.

(2) clients are allowed to access the saved data.

filter-daemon.js

```
web3.eth.filter("pending").watch(
    function(error,result){
        if (!error) {
            var transaction = web3.eth.getTransaction(result);
            console.log(transaction);
            // save the transaction somewhere (e.g. DB)
        }
    }
)
```

output

```
{ blockHash: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  blockNumber: null,
  from: '0xa3ac96fbe4b0dce5f6f89a715ca00934d68f6c37',
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: { [String: '100000000000'] s: 1, e: 11, c: [ 100000000000 ] },
  hash: '0x1ba953d7a009af9b65763f43ee4e14e11ed7ba1051c4a75bd27faf706cb5c0f6',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 83,
  to: '0x4f7d630814447f1b4c0719bb7a259c2bfd63f174',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: { [String: '410000000000000000'] s: 1, e: 17, c: [ 4100 ] },
  v: '0x29',
  r: '0x89d0370711ab688b0a46c1bbd512ce523f2c239186a3b84c87ea277dd73489ee',
  s: '0x2dfe2dc4b0719883f683199c35690189d1aebdb33eb394ba7f8392069fe3bd00' }
```

I hope there are another easier ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the state from the "pending" block.

```
{
"id": 1,
"jsonrpc": 2.0,
"method": "eth_getBalance",
"params": ["0x<address>", "pending"]
}
```

https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getBalance